# Confusion about list types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

As far as I understand `[a]` means that there can be a list that can have any number of nested lists inside.

```hs
f :: [a] -> a
f (x:xs) = x
```

It is possible to call `f [[1,2]]` or `f [[[True]]]]` without issues.

What I don't understand on the other hand is why does `[1] :: [a]` give an error in the `ghci`.

```
ghci> [1] :: [a]
<interactive>:20:2: error: [GHC-39999]
    * No instance for `Num a1' arising from the literal `1'
      Possible fix:
        add (Num a1) to the context of
          an expression type signature:
            forall a1. [a1]
    * In the expression: 1
      In the expression: [1] :: [a]
      In an equation for `it': it = [1] :: [a]
```

How come does it work when calling a function and it does not when defining the type of a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that `f :: [a] -> a` and `[1] :: [a]` both have in common is that they are both attempts to *narrow* the type of the thing being annotated. In the case of `f`, you are specifying the type of whatever gets assigned to `f`, while in the case of `[1]` you are specifying the type of `[1]` itself.

`[a] -> a` is no less specific than the inferred type of `\(x:xs) -> x`, so the type checker does not complain.

`[a]` is strictly *less* specific than the inferred type `Number a => [a]` of `[1]`, so the type checker *does* complain.

Answer (score 1):

Well you use `[1] :: [a]`, the problem is not the list. If you use `[1] :: [a]`, then Haskell reasons that `1 :: a`. Now if you say `:: a`, it means "where `1` can be of *any* type". Any? No, not any. It can be of all *`Num`erical* types. So you add a type constraint to it:

```
[1] :: Num a => [a]
```

so then we get:

```
ghci> f ([1] :: Num a => [a])
1
```

Comment: That sort of makes sense but what prevents haskell from rejecting `f [1,2,3] ` because `1` is not "Any type?"

Why do I need to specify the `Num` constraint when I construct a list but I do not need to do that when I call a function?

Coming from a Java background I would expect to be able to define a list that has any type and just create a generic list of objects.

Comment: @FilatNicolae: the `1` is the problem. In your function you say "for `f`, *any* type `a`, it will map an `[a]` (list of `a`s) to `a`). As for `[False]` for example, Haskell simply derives that it is a `Bool`. If you would use `f [1]`, it will default to `Integer`, so it will see `1` as an `Integer`.

Comment: @FilatNicolae: fwiw, I often see the type systems of Haskell and Java a bit as the opposite. In Java, if you use `Object x = 1;` then `1` is an `Integer`, which is a subclass of `Object`, so the type says it is *an* `Object`, whereas that does not work for Haskell, since it says, that the trick should hold for *any* `Object`.

Comment: I see. Why can't Haskell _derive_ that the `a` will be `False` if I do `[False] :: a`

Comment: @FilatNicolae: it can, but you here claim that `False` can be any type. So if you claim `[False] :: [a]`, then I could want `a` to be a `String`, or an `Int`, and the compiler of course has a problem with the fact that `False` is a data contructor of the `Bool` type, so it can not be any type, it is a `Bool`, and that is the only possible type.

Comment: Can you expand a bit further why the type system of Java and Haskell are oposite? I think that is the point where my confusion lies in. 
How does haskell interpret something like `Object x = 1;`?

Comment: @FilatNicolae In Java, the name `x` can be assigned *any* value, because all types are subclasses of `Object`. In Haskell, the unconstrained type variable doesn't represent *any* type, so much as it represents *all* types. If the only thing you know about `x` is that it has type `[a]`, you can't really do anything with the elements of the list. `head x + 1`, for example, isn't legal because you don't know if the elements of `x` have `Num` instances. `head x` works because it doesn't *matter* what types the elements are; `head` will work with all of them.

Comment: @Filat When you say `[False] :: [a] `, it seems that you are expecting that to mean "there is some type `a` for which `[False]` has type `[a]`". I presume you expect the compiler to figure out that can only be true if the type variable `a` is chosen as the type `Bool`. But that's **not** what `[False] :: [a]` means; instead it means "no matter what type `a` any other person chooses, `[False]` can be used as type `[a]` for that chosen `a`". That's obviously wrong, since I could choose something other than `Bool`, like `IO String` (I can't use `False` as an IO operation that produces a string!).

Comment: @Filat Fundamentally in Haskell, when you say that a thing has some type, you are declaring what other people can do with your thing. If the type you use has variables in it, you are saying they can do *anything* they can think of that works with *any* choice of type for that variable. So you then can't define your thing using any specific type; you have to define it using only features that would work with *any* possible type. This is very restrictive (and restrictions like that are actually a very powerful feature; it's how the compiler catches bugs for you, by noticing when you break them).